# Can't assign const to state value, returns undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I am trying to map through some values, but keep getting errors about the map function. When I try to assign a const to be equal to the state, it becomes undefined. I have the state logged in the console, and get the results back:

```
species: Array(3)
0: {species_ID: 1, species: "Dog"}
1: {species_ID: 2, species: "Cat"}
2: {species_ID: 3, species: "Hamster"}
length: 3
```

But when I try to assign it to a const in the render method, logging the console gives me undefined.

I have tried mapping the state directly in the map method to avoid this step, but get errors regarding map not being a function.

```
{this.state.species && this.state.species.map (speciestype => {
                        return (
                        <option key={speciestype.species_ID} value={speciestype.species_ID}>
                            {speciestype.species}
                        </option>
                    )}
                    )}
```

This is what the code looks like currently:

```
render() {
   const {speciesdata} = this.state.species; 
   console.log(speciesdata);
    return (
```

My map function then looks like this:

```
{speciesdata && speciesdata.map (speciestype => {
                        return (
                        <option key={speciestype.species_ID} value={speciestype.species_ID}>
                            {speciestype.species}
                        </option>
                    )}
                    )}
```

But since speciesdata is undefined (according to console), the dropdown is empty.

How come I can't assign speciesdata to the state I know exists?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const {speciesdata} = this.state.species;
```

will not work because this.state.species does not contain any object called `speciesdata`. You should either do this:

```
const { species } = this.state;
```

or this:

```
const speciesdata = [...this.state.species];
```

Then try rewritting your map in this way that it checks not only if it exists but if species is an array or not as well:

```
{
  species && 
  species.length &&
  species.map(speciestype => (
   <option key={speciestype.species_ID} value={speciestype.species_ID}>
      {speciestype.species}
   </option>
  ))
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that! Didn't realise you had to call the const the same value as the array, and obviously had errors in my map syntax. How come there doesn't need to be a return function in it? I have other maps that use {} and then a return function. 
Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome! In ES6 syntax you can either write `map(a => {return a})` or `map(a=> (a))`. You can read more about arrow functions here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

LiJonas answered this with the following code:

This:

```
const {speciesdata} = this.state.species;
```

will not work because this.state.species does not contain any object called speciesdata. You should either do this:

```
const { species } = this.state;
```

or this:

```
const speciesdata = [...this.state.species];
```

Then try rewritting your map in this way that it checks not only if it exists but if species is an array or not as well:

```
{
  species && 
  species.length &&
  species.map(speciestype => (
   <option key={speciestype.species_ID} value={speciestype.species_ID}>
      {speciestype.species}
   </option>
  ))
}
```